# Can not find header in Automake

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I was learning GNU autotools (autoconf, automake) with this helloworld example. My project tree is like this:

```
|-- aclocal.m4
    |-- AUTHORS
    |-- autom4te.cache
    |   |-- output.0
    |   |-- output.1
    |   |-- requests
    |   |-- traces.0
    |   `-- traces.1
    |-- autoscan.log
    |-- ChangeLog
    |-- config.h.in
    |-- configure
    |-- configure.ac
    |-- COPYING
    |-- depcomp
    |-- include
    |   |-- hello.hpp
    |   `-- world.hpp
    |-- INSTALL
    |-- install-sh
    |-- lib
    |   |-- hello.cpp
    |   |-- Makefile.am
    |   |-- Makefile.in
    |   `-- world.cpp
    |-- Makefile.am
    |-- Makefile.in
    |-- missing
    |-- NEWS
    |-- README
    `-- src
        |-- main.cpp
        |-- Makefile.am
        `-- Makefile.in
```

I build like this:

```
$autoreconf -vfi 
$./configure
$make
```

... and get a compilation failure:

> ```
> Making all in src
> make[2]: Entering directory `/home/suddin/package_directory/src'
> g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -g -O2 -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo -c -o main.o main.cpp
> main.cpp:7:21: fatal error: hello.hpp: No such file or directory
>  #include "hello.hpp"
>                      ^
> ```

I was able to build successfully by changing my `#include` directives to these:

```
#include "../include/hello.hpp"
#include "../include/world.hpp"
```

, but I would prefer to keep them as they are:

```
#include "hello.hpp"
#include "world.hpp"
```

My `src/Makefile.am` file contains the following line; why does it not resolve the issue?

```
helloWorld_CXXFLAGS=-I../include      ##Add path to header file
```

For context, here are all my Makefile.am files:

===== src/Makefile.am ======================

```
bin_PROGRAMS=helloworld
helloworld_SOURCES=main.cpp
helloworld_CXXFLAGS= -I../include ## add path to headerfiles
helloworld_LDADD=../lib/libhw.a ## link with static library
```

===== lib/Makefile.am =======================

```
noinst_LIBRARIES=libhw.a ## static library which is not to be installed
libhw_a_SOURCES=hello.cpp hello.hpp world.cpp world.hpp
libhw_a_CXXFLAGS=-I../include ## add path to headerfiles
```

===== Makefile.am (top level) =================

```
 SUBDIRS=lib src ## processing subdirs in given order
```

Comment: I observe that the compilation command that `make` issues for file `main.cpp` does not include the needed `-I` directive.  This is the proximal cause of the compilation error.  I also note that your question has  inconsistent name capitalization: the text says you've set a `make` variable named `helloWorld_CXXFLAGS` (with a capital 'W'); if indeed you have done so then that is irrelevant to building a target named `helloworld` (with lowercase 'w').  Your `src/Makefile.am` uses the appropriate capitalization, however.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the three `Makefile.am` files you have presented, and I was unable to use them as a model for reproducing the error.  I am therefore inclined to suspect that the actual situation is different in some way than you have presented.  Perhaps one or more variable names really are wrong, or perhaps you did not really re-run `autoreconf` since the last time you modified your `Makefile.am` files (and you have maintainer mode disabled).

Comment: first of all helloWorld_CXXFLAGS was my typing mistake .'w' should be small 'w', but how to include header using -I directive ,  those header file are kept in " include"  directory ?

Comment: As I said, I was unable to reproduce your problem.  What you presented should work, and a slightly simplified version (still referencing a header from the include/ directory) *did* work for me.  Whatever the problem is, you do not seem to have captured it in the question.

Comment: sorry you're right, I recheck my code now , it was just a typing mistake, "helloWorld_CXXFLAGS " should be "helloworld_CXXFLAGS" , and all compiled successfully , thanks again for the help.

Comment: If you declare your includes directory with `-I../include`, you probably want to use `#include <hello.hpp>` instead of `#include "hello.hpp"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing mistake, "helloWorld_CXXFLAGS " should be "helloworld_CXXFLAGS".

Comment: No, it should be `helloworld_CPPFLAGS` as it's a preprocessor feature. See answer by @ndim  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45778130/611560

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
helloworld_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/include
```

to compile all object files for `foo` adding the include dir from the **source tree**.